# MySQL Cluster work well but ndb_desc doesn't work

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I have deployed and configured MySQL cluster. It works fine.

---

```
ndb_mgm> show

Connected to Management Server at: localhost:1186

Cluster Configuration

[ndbd(NDB)]2 node(s)

id=2@192.168.56.2  (mysql-5.6.19 ndb-7.3.6, Nodegroup: 0, *)

id=3@192.168.56.3  (mysql-5.6.19 ndb-7.3.6, Nodegroup: 0)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)]1 node(s)

id=1@192.168.56.1  (mysql-5.6.19 ndb-7.3.6)

[mysqld(API)]1 node(s)

id=4@192.168.56.4  (mysql-5.6.19 ndb-7.3.6)
```

---

I am reading the manual section about how to use MySQL cluster program http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-cluster-programs.html

On SQL Node - 192.168.56.4, I am running:

shell> ndb_desc -c 192.168.56.1

I receive message:

```
Unable to connect to management server.

NDBT_ProgramExit: 1 - Failed
```

I did ping and telnet successful to management node - 192.168.56.1:1186 from sql node - 192.168.56.4 There is no firewall between them.

What is cause of the problem ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of problem is no free nodeid to allocate for ndb_desc. ndb_desc will attempt to connect to management node as api node thus it need free node. To make free node for ndb_desc, management node need to have empty [mysqld] in global config config.ini *(in production, I think the use empty [mysqld] is no safe because any client is possible to connect to managment node to get free nodeid)*

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who met the same problem but the solution from @luke didnt work, try to restart the data nodes. mine working after i did that. [link to my thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/224634/config-file-and-parameters-for-ndb-desc/224708)