# config file and parameters for ndb_desc

Tags: mysql-5.7, mysql-cluster, ndbcluster

I'm trying to execute `ndb_desc` from API client. The config and parameters are as below:

my.cnf in mysqld:

```
[mysql_cluster]
ndb-connectstring=192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2

server-id=5
log-bin=mysql-bin
```

config.ini in mgmd: (part of it)

```
-- ...
[mysqld]
hostname=192.168.1.5
--- ...
```

Situation: there are 2x mgmd, 2x data-node, and 2x mysqld.

Parameters tried to call ndb_desc: `# ndb_desc -c 192.168.1.1 --ndb-nodeid=7 -d db_name -t tb_name`

Above response with error: `ndb_desc: [ERROR] unknown variable 'server-id=5`

On changing `my.cnf`, removing these two lines of `server-id` and `log-bin`, then the error response after calling ndb_desc will be as follow:

```
Unable to connect to management server. 
NDBT_ProgramExit: 1 - Failed
```

There is no firewall, ping to the management is running fine.

So the question: how to exec ndb_desc (with correct parameters)? what is the correct my.cnf/config.ini for setting up the node-id?

Some links i have tried to check before posting this:
[mysql-cluster-work-well-but-ndb-desc-doesnt-work](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72978/mysql-cluster-work-well-but-ndb-desc-doesnt-work), [mysql:ndb_desc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-cluster-excerpt/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-programs-ndb-desc.html), [mysql:connection-string](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-connection-strings.html), [grokbase](https://grokbase.com/t/mysql/cluster/081n5p65ts/works-ndb-desc-and-other-tools-dont), and several hours of googling around.

update1: changed the config.ini on mgmd for emtpy mysqld section, `ndb_mgm -e show` output:

```
[mysqld(API)]   3 node(s)
id=5    @192.168.1.5  (mysql-5.7.23 ndb-7.6.7)
id=6    @192.168.1.6  (mysql-5.7.23 ndb-7.6.7)
id=7 (not connected, accepting connect from any host)
```

ndb_desc still has the same response: `Unable to connect to management server.`

update2: from mgmd node, saw this log: `WARNING  -- Failed to allocate nodeid for API at 192.168.1.5. Returned error: 'Id 7 already allocated by another node.`

update3: changed config.ini, added `[api] nodeid=7 host=192.168.1.5`. log still the same: `WARNING  -- Failed to allocate nodeid for API at 192.168.11.51. Returned error: 'No free node id found for mysqld(API).`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the changes i made to make this work:

1. add empty api node at the end of mgmd config.ini: `[api]`
2. stop both of ndbd from mgmd: `ndb_mgm -e "3 stop" | "4 stop"`
3. stop both of mgmd: `ndb_mgm -e "1 stop" | "2 stop"`
4. start mgmd 1: `ndb_mgmd --initial --reload --config-file=/var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini`
5. start mgmd 2: `ndb_mgmd --initial --config-file=/var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini`
6. start ndbd manually: ssh to the machine and run `ndbd`
7. wait until all node connected
8. make sure my.cnf at mysql node is having: `[mysql_cluster] ndb-connectstring=192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2`, or can add `-c` on ndb_desc param later
9. run ndb_desc at mysql node: `ndb_desc -p -d db_name -t tb_name`

the important missing part after adding **empty api node** is **restarting the data node**

link to source: [No free node id found](https://grokbase.com/t/mysql/cluster/115548r4nh/no-free-node-id-found)